# Regex in perl, match newline AND first word of next line

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that looks like

```
title="title1"  
artist="artist1"  
title="title2"  
artist="artis2"  
title="title3"  
artist="artist3"
```

And so on

this command
`perl -pe 's/title="(.*?)"\n//ig' list.txt`

Is not working as I'd hope.  If I do that alone, I get just the artist lines, BUT if I do this

`perl -pe 's/title="(.*?)"\nartist//ig' list.txt`

It doesn't match at all.
I've tried with and without the /g and tried with the addition of a /m
I've look at the file in nano, and I don't see any additional characters between the final " in each line and the "artist" in the next.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  (I'm using perl rather than sed, because the regex that generates this list uses a negative lookahead).

My goal is to be able to use a line like below
`perl -pe 's/title="(.*?)"\nartist="(.*?)"(?:\n|$)/\2 - \1/ig' list.txt`

That would output something like

```
artist1 - title1  
artist2 - title2  
artist3 - title3
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'll edit an additional section into the post

Comment: Open it in `vim` and issue the command `:set list` to see if you might have other unprinted characters in the way, _e.g._ Windows-style newlines, `\r\n`.

Comment: Try to slurp the file with `-0777`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a ["slurp"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) approach, you can use this regex:

```
(^title="([^"]+)")\s*\R(^artist="([^"]+)")\s*(?:\R|\z)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB4kN1/1)

Then given your example:

```
$ echo "$art" 
title="title1"  
artist="artist1"  
title="title2"  
artist="artis2"  
title="title3"  
artist="artist3"
```

Just "slurp" the file with `-0777` and print `$2` and `$4`:

```
$ echo "$art" | perl -0777 -lne 'while (/(^title="([^"]+)")\s*\R(^artist="([^"]+)")\s*(?:\R|\z)/gm) { print "$4 - $2\n"}'
artist1 - title1
artis2 - title2
artist3 - title3
```

Comment: Slurp mode looks like it does what I want, and my original regex looks like it will work, I used this regex: 's/title="(.*?)"\nartist="(.*?)"(?:\n|$)/\2 - \1\n/ig'

Comment: (To add to that last comment, I didn't need to do the modification you did to negate the ", as I used ? on the .* to make it lazy.

Comment: Great. You may want to consider two modifications: 1) Use `\R` or `$` rather than `\n` in the regex. The `\R` is a metacharacter for any sequence of line endings (windows, etc) and 2) you may want to add `\h*` or `\s*` after the closing quotes to catch invisible trailing line endings like you had in your example. So like this: `^title="(.*?)"\h*\R^artist="(.*?)"\h*$`

Comment: *"I didn't need to do the modification you did to negate the `"`"* Non-greedy matches can be fickle, and I highly recommend that you stick with `"([^"]*)"`. There are many posts on Stack Overflow like [*Non-greedy regex acts greedily*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971608/non-greedy-regex-acts-greedily) where people have misunderstood what a non-greedy match does

Comment: @Borodin Normally I'd agree, but in my case, lazy matching works here since the file is in a specific format, and won't ever have a case that doesn't work in this manner since I'm generating the data it's processing.  (Dawg, it wasn't from me, no idea he did since he's agreeing with your original comment)

Answer (score 3):

Your substitution

```
s/title="(.*?)"\n//ig
```

is replacing any line that looks like `title="xxx"` with nothing. It is deleting those lines.

It's unclear what you want, but if your requirement is to remove the `title=` and the quotes then you should use

```
perl -pe 's/title="(.*?)"/$1/i' myfile
```

The `/g` modifier is superfluous unless you expect many titles in a one line from the file

---

### Update

If you want to pair titles with artists then you really need a script file. This should do what you need. The data is taken directly from your question

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $title;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    if ( /title="([^"]*)"/ ) {
        $title = $1;
    }
    elsif ( /artist="([^"]*)"/ ) {
        say "$1 - $title";
    }
}


__DATA__
title="title1"
artist="artist1"
title="title2"
artist="artis2"
title="title3"
artist="artist3"
```

#### output

```
artist1 - title1
artis2 - title2
artist3 - title3
```

Answer (score 1):

You never mentioned what you're trying to do. If you want to extract the titles and artists, you 'll want something like this:

```
our $s = q|
title="title1"
artist="artist1"
title="title2"
artist="artis2"
title="title3"
artist="artist3"
|;

my @matches = $s =~ /^title="(.*?)".*?^artist="(.*?)"/smg;

print join(';', @matches);
```

This prints

```
title1;artist1;title2;artis2;title3;artist3
```

Comment: Sorry fixed this a minute ago. Guess you can't see it yet. Just missed the end of the line when I copied the text.

Answer (score 1):

IF your file is exactly as you describe it, you can use this command that reads two lines at once. In this way you avoid the slurp mode:

```
perl -pe '$_.=<>;s/.*?"(.*?)".*?"(.*?)"/$2 - $1/s' file
```

if you need something more explicit, you can use:

```
perl -pe 'if (/^title="/){$_.=<>;s/^.*?"(.*?)"\h*\Rartist="(.*?)"\h*/$2 - $1/}' file
```